# How to compute a summation to a specified number of terms in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I want to compute a summation to a specified number of terms in c#, such as

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssipn.png

(replace 100 with the number of terms I would compute).

This value is equal to (1/2)+(1/4)+(1/8)+(1/16)+...+(1/2^100).

I was thinking to use a while loop that adds up 1/2^x with x from 1-100, and sum them up, and I know how to calculate each individual term, but how do I sum each term up without explicitly declaring 100 variables?

Thanks for the support!

(I don't need a whole program, only a while loop class.)

And no, I think that double offers enough precision. I'm applying this to other arithmetic sequences.

Comment: Well, your equation Σ[1/(2^n)] can be rewritten as 1-(2^(-n)), so you could do it with a single line: `Double x = 1 - (2^-n)`.  But I imagine you're after something more reusable.  :-)

Comment: Actually, I just tried that out, and you're going to suffer rounding errors long before you reach 100 terms.  Unless you're using specialised math software, you won't get an answer with any precission.

Comment: `decimal` might have enough precision for it, i think.  It's 128 bits.

Comment: Actually, scratch that -- the significand is only 96 bits.  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Jonathan's answer, here is my finished code (using [w3b.sine](http://sine.codeplex.com/) for arbitrary math):

```
using System;
using W3b.Sine;

namespace summation
{
    public class Program
    {
        static BigNum doSummation(int maxPower)
        {
            BigNum sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= maxPower; i++)
            {
                sum += Math.Pow(2, i * -1);
            }
            return sum;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(doSummation(100));
        }
    }
}
```

W3b.Sine needs to be included in the assembly references.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with LINQ:

```
int upper = 100;
var items = Enumerable.Range(1, upper);

double total = items.Select(i => 1.0 / Math.Pow(2.0, i)).Sum();
```

Comment: Actually, this works too. I'm going to see which one is easier to apply. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you don't need the whole program, but it's so short, it's hard not to!

```
public double doSummation(int maxPower) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxPower; i++) {
        sum += Math.pow(2, i * -1); // 2^(-1) + 2^(-2) + 2^(-3) + ... + 2^(-1 * maxPower)
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Then the summation for the first 100 terms would be:

```
doSummation(100)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I'm currently tweaking it for my mod of the Chudnovsky algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
 var upperbounds = 100;
    var sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1;i <= upperbounds ; i++ )
    {
      sum += 1/Math.Pow(2, i);
    }
```